# How to read nested objects in a json file as dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a .json file with content:

> {"success":true,"code":"SUCCESS","data":{"from":1514745000000,"to":1522175400000,"transactionData":[{"name":"Recharge
> & bill
> payments","paymentInstruments":[{"type":"TOTAL","count":4200,"amount":1845307.4673655091}]},{"name":"Peer-to-peer
> payments","paymentInstruments":[{"type":"TOTAL","count":1871,"amount":1.2138655299749982E7}]},{"name":"Merchant
> payments","paymentInstruments":[{"type":"TOTAL","count":298,"amount":452507.168646613}]},{"name":"Financial
> Services","paymentInstruments":[{"type":"TOTAL","count":33,"amount":10601.419933464953}]},{"name":"Others","paymentInstruments":[{"type":"TOTAL","count":256,"amount":184689.8662902223}]}]},"responseTimestamp":1630501487199}

I want to convert it into a pandas data frame. But when I apply:

```
a = pd.read_json('/1.json')
```

I get output like this:
[image]

How can I get it in the correct pandas DataFrame format?

Comment: How exactly, in which format do you want the data to be, the dataframe is read in same format as the data is present, can you post the desired table please

Comment: I want data in of transactionData which is in form of list in a dataframe

Comment: can you post the desired table please

Comment: wrong url for image

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar updated https://imgur.com/5UfwPKp

Comment: okay wait a minute, providing answer

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Thank you very much u r life saver i am trying to do it for 2 hour 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to read data key in your dictionary. You can load the json as dictionary in memory and then use pandas to convert the same to a dataframe.

As discussed in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73002415/how-to-read-json-file-in-dataframe/73002774?noredirect=1#comment128937695_73002774) : This is the expected output

[image]

##### Solution :

Here we are reading the json data first, then converting the `data >>> transaction` key to a pandas dataframe.

The above gives us a dataframe containing list values using [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for `paymentInstruments`. We need to unravel it such that we transform each element of a list-like to a row, replicating index values.

Once the values in lists are replicated we can convert the dictionries obtained to columns using [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) or [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

##### Reading Data

```
import json

f = open(r'/1.json')
data = json.load(f)
                           
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['data']['transactionData'])
```

##### Pre-processing and generating Data

```
df = df.explode('paymentInstruments')
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('paymentInstruments').apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1)
```

##### Output

This gives us the expected output

[image]

##### Alternatively :

Here is [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) solution

```
df = df.explode('paymentInstruments')
df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df.pop('paymentInstruments'))], axis = 1)
```

This gives us :

[image]

Comment: I think there is some error in syntax in 3rd line there are 2 closing brackets..

Comment: updated the answer, did it work for you?

Comment: I am getting : https://imgur.com/96z6WOs This error

Comment: sorry missed a line, please try this

Comment: this is what u tried right? `f = open(r'/1.json')
data = json.load(f)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. It was before you added the line.